# How do I create the Jquery goldfrapp changing background images

Tags: jquery, background, fade, effect

I'm trying to create a rotating background like the clouds on Goldfrapps site. I've searched on google for changing background animation jquery but these don't have the same effect I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at:

- [CrossSlide plugin](http://tobia.github.com/CrossSlide/)